# How can I use a for loop to read until the scanned character is a newline?

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, while-loop

I am a C beginner who has been assigned to write a program that uses pointers to reverse a message. I am having trouble getting the for loop that reads the characters to break after it reads a newline and I don't want to use a while loop.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
        //declare string
        char reverse[100];

        //declare pointer
        char *first;

        //set pointer to point to first element of array
        first = &reverse[0];

        //get chars until end of input  
        printf("Enter a message:");
        for (first = reverse; *first != '\n'; first++){
                scanf("%c", first);
                printf("%c", *first);
        }

        //reverse chars one by one
        printf("Reversal: ");
        for (first; first >= reverse; first--){
                printf("%c", *first);
        }
        printf("\n");


        return 0;
}
```

Thank you! Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Don't use `scanf` to read a single char, use `getchar`.  (Really, don't use `scanf` for anything.)

Comment: `reverse` is not initialized.  So the first time you read `*first` in the check of the for loop, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that you `scanf` into `*first`, and then you increment `first`, and then you check if the value of `*first` is `\n`.  But the value you are checking is *not* the one you just wrote, because you incremented the pointer.  Also, you *must* check the value returned by `scanf`.  You *could* do `for( first = reverse; scanf("%c", first) == 1 && *first != '\n' && first - reverse < sizeof reverse; first += 1 ) ...`, but it is much more idiomatic to use `getchar`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for the input. I am supposed to use scanf and implement this function as part of an assignment. I implemented the code you specified ```(for( first = reverse; scanf("%c", first) == 1 && *first != '\n' && first - reverse < sizeof reverse; first += 1 ) ...)```, but it produced strange output. Sorry for the ignorant question, but how would I actually initialize char reverse[100]; to prevent undefined behavior?

Comment: Initiailization can be as easy as `char reverse[100] = {0}` or `char reverse[100] = "";`. But the better way to avoid the UB is to *not* look at entries in the array that have not yet been assigned.

Comment: If you are getting "strange output", perhaps you are still doing `scanf` inside the loop body.  Need to see code.

Answer (score 0):

You have effectively implemented `gets`, a function so dangerous it was [removed from the language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965), with a side of [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) because `*first != '\n'` is executed at the start of each iteration of the loop, and `*first` is an indeterminate value at this point.

`first--` and `first >= reverse` are also a problem as holding a pointer value to *one before* the start of an object is also [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). It is valid C to hold (but not use with unary `*`) an address *one past* the end of an array object (C11 §6.5.6).

Note, using `getchar` would be preferable to `scanf`.

If you do not want the newline in the buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main(void) {
    char buffer[SIZE];
    char *dest = buffer;

    for (; dest - buffer < sizeof buffer - 1; dest++)
        if (1 != scanf("%c", dest) || '\n' == *dest)
            break;

    *dest = 0;

    while (dest > buffer)
        putchar(*--dest);

    putchar('\n');
}
```

If you want the newline in the buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main(void) {
    char buffer[SIZE];
    char *dest = buffer;

    for (; dest - buffer < sizeof buffer - 1;)
        if (1 != scanf("%c", dest) || '\n' == *dest++)
            break;

    *dest = 0;

    while (dest > buffer)
        putchar(*--dest);

    putchar('\n');
}
```

Note the difference in when `dest` is incremented.

```
while (dest > buffer)
    putchar(*--dest);
```

works by starting at the null-terminating character, and printing each element that comes *before* the current one, until our current element is the start of the array.

---

This can also get extremely terse, and you may be tempted to write something like

```
/* newline in buffer */
for (; dest - buffer < sizeof buffer - 1 && 1 == scanf("%c", dest) && '\n' != *dest; dest++);
```

but use of the `break` keyword can help to keep it readable.